# tables across page (ltxtable vs ltablex)

Tags: tables, longtable, ltxtable

In the past I worked with the `ltxtable` package, which unfortunately require the table in a separate file.

Now I found the `ltablex` package which claims to be a rewrite (or it rewrites) the `tabularx` package.

I wonder which of both is better? Both are more than 15 years old (both from 1995).
Any recommendations?

Comment: ltablex seem to introduce some caption related bugs, as described in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/ltablex-caption-error-or-bug

Comment: There is also the `tabu` package which seems to be very feature-rich. It is very new and supports a lot of things.

Comment: By careful with "what is better" questions here. Subjective threads / answers are not wanted on a Q&A site. You might want to rephrase it a little.

Comment: Just as a note, if you really want to keep using `ltxtable` you could use the [`filecontents`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) package to keep everything in the same file.

Comment: I agree with @wh1t3, but IMHO everything complex, like a large table, should be in a separate file anyway.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I know that asking for *better* is a bad defined question, but since I know only one of them I was looking for arguments for or against them.  I know filecontents and use it. And tabu is on my radar, but I want at least have a 'standard' version to compare it to tabu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

`ltablex` seems to introduce some caption related bugs, as described here: [ltablex + \caption[]{…} = error or bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7977/)

On the other hand, if for some reason you must use `ltxtable` you could use the filecontents package to keep everything in the same file.

Other, newer, still maintained packages which have similar features are available on CTAN, like e.g. `tabu`.