# How to typset an "aligned" glossary (list of acronyms) with automatic widest-entry calculation (using glossaries-extra)?

Tags: vertical-alignment, glossaries, acronyms, wrap, glossaries-extra

I am currently using the package `glossaries-extra` with the `IEEEtran` class (in 2-column). I need to typeset a list of acronyms. So far, I have managed to get the basics working. However, the list of acronyms are not currently aligned, i.e. the glossary entries are not in-flush, which makes the document slightly jarring to the eyes.

Here's the MWE that I have so far

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage[debrief]{silence}
\documentclass[nofonttune]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{microtype}

%%%%%%% glossaries ---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[nomain, acronym, nonumberlist, nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}} % link colouring to match normal text, ie black
\newacronym{adc}{ADC}{Analog to Digital Converter}
\newacronym{armax}{ARMAX}{Autoregressive Moving Average Model with Exogenous Inputs}
\newacronym{laser}{LASER}{Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation}
\newacronym{gigo}{GIGO}{Garbage In Garbage Out}

\setglossarypreamble[acronym]{\small}

\makeglossaries
%%% end of glossaries --------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\title{Some bombastic title}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Hello world. 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Intro

\glsaddall{}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output in the PDF obtained by running `pdflatex`

[image: Acronyms with broken indentation]

How can I get LaTeX to automatically align the acronyms list by using the width pf the widest entry in the list? Also For overly long acronym expansion, I'd the text to wrap properly within the description column without encroaching into the left hand entry column.
PS: I am aware of a solution using  `bib2gls` in conjunction with `glossaries-extra`. However,  I cannot switch to this system for various technical reasons (my co-authors do not have nor want to run Java etc.).

Comment: You might be interested in the `alttree` style as suggested in this related question: [Long table with X column for usage with glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392843/134144)